# Unable to cast to protocol conformance for init

Tags: swift, syntax

Casting a generic, within a function, to conform to SomeProtocol that has an init function. It isn't possible?

```
public func doSomething<Entity>(foo: Entity) throws -> Entity {

  let aValue = someVariableSomewhere.performFunction()

  // stuff happens

  _ = (Entity.self as! SomeProtocol)(record: aValue) //fails

  // stuff happens

  // returns something
}
```

'SomeProtocol' has the function

```
init(record: String)
```

Comment: How does it "fail"? It seems to compile well enough (trivially correcting the undeclared `fetchManager`, the wrong use of `Error` and the empty `.failure` case). Without a complete compilable code fragment it's impossible to guess how it fails - could it be that `foo` is an optional?

Comment: @Grimxn The clue is in the title of the post. Of course it won't run, there loads of missing code. See annotation marks like 'whatever' and 'bar' haha. What possessed you to try and run it? Awesome.

Comment: I will edit the code a bit more to make it even clearer.

Comment: I think you should initialize the object directly like below as you are already checking the type of the object.

`let foo = SomeProtocol.init(record: aValue)`

Comment: @Kamran SomeProtocol.init(record: aValue) ??? Don't you mean Entity.init(record: aValue) ??? Anyway that won't work because Entity has no type information without casting. And casting gives error.

Comment: As you updated the method signature, you can initialize the object as below,

`let object = type(of: foo as! SomeProtocol).init(record: "stringValue")`

Comment: @kamran that works! if you post it as an official answer, I will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to the protocol for initialization as following,

```
let object = type(of: foo as! SomeProtocol).init(record: "stringValue")
```

Comment: Hi @Kamran. Ye, I'm trying to avoid declaring Entity as CloudKitInitiable in the function signature because I am trying to keep CloudKitInitiable internal. I know it's not cool to keep the caller guessing and I probably won't stick to this idea. You say 'you can not initialize the non-nominal type of a generic inside a method' which is fine. But do you have a link to something that proves that is the case? If so, I will accept answer.

Comment: @user9400730 please confirm.